# Migration from Java 1.4 to Java 17, how to handle deprecated or removed packages

Tags: linux, jax-rs, java-17, hp-ux, javax.xml

We are migrating from Java 1.4 to Java 17, in our codes we are using javax.xml, javax.jws packages which were removed in Java11. We need to find an alternative for this. We don't use maven.

We are not sure where to start. Also, we are migrating from Unix to Linux. So, need something which is compatible compatible with latest RHEL OS.

Comment: What is “javax.ws”? Do you mean “javax.jws” or “javax.xml.ws”? Did these APIs even exist under Java 1.4?

Comment: Yeah, I meant javax.jws

Comment: The [`javax.jws` package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/jws/package-summary.html) only consists of `enum` and annotation types. How were you using it with Java 1.4?